# Как нарисовать анимированный курсор на форме?

Tags: c, winapi

Использую, но ничего не выходит

```
DrawIconEx(hDC, 10, 10, L"a.ani", 0, 0, 1, NULL, DI_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://www.navioo.com/csharp/source_code/Load_animated_cursor_74.html)  есть хороший пример для анимированых курсоров:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
using System.IO;  

public class Form1 : Form  
{  

  public Form1() {  
        InitializeComponent();  
    try  
    {  
      this.Cursor = AdvancedCursors.Create(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "blob.ani"));  
    }  
    catch (Exception err)  
    {  
      MessageBox.Show(err.Message);  
    }  
  }  

  private void InitializeComponent()  
  {  
    this.SuspendLayout();  

    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);  
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;  
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);  
    this.Text = "Form1";  
    this.ResumeLayout(false);  
  }  


  [STAThread]  
  static void Main()  
  {  
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
    Application.Run(new Form1());  
  }  

}  

public class AdvancedCursors  
{  

  [DllImport("User32.dll")]  
  private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(String str);  

  public static Cursor Create(string filename)  
  {  
    IntPtr hCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(filename);  

    if (!IntPtr.Zero.Equals(hCursor))  
    {  
      return new Cursor(hCursor);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      throw new ApplicationException("Could not create cursor from file " + filename);  
    }  
  }  
}
```